# spring-cloud-etcd configure multiple clients for discovery

Tags: spring-cloud, etcd

I am having difficulty configuring multiple clients for auto-discovery/configuration using spring-cloud-etcd.

Is there common configuration I should be enabling to perform this?

The goal is to assess how etcd can be used in place of Netflix OSS Eureka.

Comment: It is a developer preview so you need to compile the project yourself.  There is a sample project that shows what dependencies you need to include: https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-etcd  What problems are you having specifically?

Comment: All applications appear to registering with the etcd server. note the output below from the etcd log```2015/07/8 14:36:14 etcdhttp: [PUT] /v2/keys/spring/cloud/discovery/pc-acp-svm/pc-acp-svm:8765 remote:127.0.0.1:43328
2015/07/8 14:36:20 etcdhttp: [PUT] /v2/keys/spring/cloud/discovery/pc-acp-dss/pc-acp-dss:8761 remote:127.0.0.1:43329
2015/07/8 14:36:39 etcdhttp: [PUT] /v2/keys/spring/cloud/discovery/pc-acp-svm/pc-acp-svm:8765 remote:127.0.0.1:43331
2015/07/8 14:36:43 etcdhttp: [PUT] /v2/keys/spring/cloud/discovery/pc-acp-mm/pc-acp-mm:7979 remote:127.0.0.1:43332
```

Comment: However, it does not appear that any of the applications can talk to or discover one another

Comment: I pulled all the dependencies from the sample, built the jars and included them in my gradle dependencies. I spin up my discovery service, zuul router, hystrix, and a couple of rest services.  They are not able to discover one another, so the zuul routes just 404, and the rest services that call other services just fail since ribbon can't locate them.

Comment: Do you have a project you could share?

Comment: @spencergibb I shared a github repository with you.  There is a readme that shows startup procedures. I will update it with what I was doing for this spike.

Comment: you will basically start the apps in succession like in the readme (note there are 2 that haven't been migrated yet), after staring etcd.  I modified your start script with -debug and using 2.1.0.rc0.  You see each one logging.  Please let me know if there are questions.  The service, right now is very simple, ```curl -s localhost:8765/api/status``` should show you json, calling all the other rest services, and giving you a simulation of how these services will interact with one another.

Comment: @spencergibb I didn't pass the branch to that github repo.  It is out there now.  It is called spike_etcd.  When you pull that repo, switch to that branch to checkout the etcd work.  Thanks.